# Yii2: How to log exceptions?

Tags: logging, exception, yii2, error-logging

What should happen if I log an exception? Example:

```
Yii::error(new Exception('test'));
```

Currently with my basic application template nothing happens. Nothing gets logged (further error() calls don't log either). Is this correct? Configuration is:

```
'log'          => [
  'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
  'targets'    => [
    [
      'class'  => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
      'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
    ],
  ],
],
```

I have had expected that exceptions get logged appropiately. How should I log exceptions, esp. if I want to see the trace?

**Update:**

See [Issue](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/7305) on GitHub. With Yii 2.0.6 it is possible to log exceptions.

This might be useful if you catch an exception and throw another. Then you can log the original problem. However, if you throw an exception that is based on a Yii exception you can often (or always?) attach the original exception as `$previous`. Such an exception will be logged with the previous one automatically if it does not get catched anywhere.

Answer (score 6):

I believe, your config is correct.

But you don't need to cover your exception by `Yii::error()`. There are two basic ways to log error:

**1)** Just throw any exception:

```
throw new \Exception("My error message #1");
```

**2)** Use `Yii::error()`

```
Yii::error("My error message #2");
```

The difference is that you will quietly put this second message into log without stopping your application.

Comment: Thank you so far. But what if the exception in 1) gets catched? Will it still be logged? And is `Yii::error(new Exception('test'));` not allowed or why does it prevent any logging?

Comment: 1. No, catched exception will not be logged, because it "dies" inside your try{} block and application does not know about it. Actually, the only reason why app knows about exception is: application encloses all process in its "general" try - catch. 2. Yii::error() method takes only a string as its argument, while new Exception() is an object and it's not even thrown.

Comment: I see. That was the reason why I tried to log the exception: I catch it and throw an HttpException instead (without appending the catched Exception to the HttpException to not show the internals (trace) to the client). But I want to log those incidents and I thought I just could log the whole exception. Could I realize this anyhow in a simple way? I don't want to extract the message and the trace manually. Btw: $message of Yii::error() may be a string but the called Logger::log() method accepts also other kind of objects. You can pass a e.g. a model object to Yii::error(). That's possible.

Comment: Now I see it too: you actually can log object, but Yii2 uses PDO class which appears in backtrace and app tries to serialize all backtrace while generating log message. The problem is that PDO object cannot be serialized and it causes new Exception. I'm not sure whether this case is handled properly by Yii2, but we don't see any log at the end, and I suppose that's an issue.

Answer (score 2):

To log exception fully after catching it, you can write this in your catch block

```
Yii::$app->errorHandler->logException($e);
```

You can read about error handling in yii2 [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-errorhandler#logException()-detail)